# Tiled gallery with <a>-tag around images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm using pure CSS (Bootstrap 4) to display a tiled gallery.
To do this, I'm using the flexbox elements from Bootstrap (`d-flex` and `flex-wrap`).

Everything works fine if I only use `<img>`-tags.
But I want to wrap the images with an `<a>`-tag to link to a lightbox.
If I do this, the gallery breaks.

Here's an example of my code: https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/RMrbzK

Is there anything I could do? I've tried to use the CSS from the `img` but it doesn't work.

And as optional question: Is it possible to force the gallery to display in two columns? The last image is almost square but shows as widescreen rectangle.

Comment: flex-grow need to go to the flex item, so you need to set it for the a --- but it won't be enough

Comment: I tried that too, but it also breaks the gallery

Comment: yes becasue the image now are inside, so you need to do it differently, am thinking about a fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably achieve what you want if you make the `<a>` tag a flex item and flex container as well. So try adding this style:

```
.img-gallery a {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display:flex;
}
```

Here is an updated [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zWrYJq)

Answer (score 2):

Make the anchors `display:flex` too:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rdxNLX

```
.img-gallery img {object-fit: cover; height: 200px; flex-grow: 1;}

.img-gallery > a {
    vertical-align:middle;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 2px; 
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: thanks! zgood was a bit fast but I marked your answer as useful.